# Retrieve a list of related products for a given upgrade code in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-installer

I use the `windows` crate in Rust to retrieve a list of related products for a given upgrade code, but my code returned `error 87 (-2147024809) The parameter is set incorrectly`.

I tried like this:

```
use windows::Win32::System::ApplicationInstallationAndServicing::MsiEnumRelatedProductsA;
use winapi::shared::winerror::HRESULT_FROM_WIN32;
fn main() {
    let upgrade_code = "23170F69-40C1-2702-0000-000004000000";    
    // Enumerate related products and print their names
    let mut index = 0;
    loop {
        let mut product_buf = vec![0u8; 1024];
        let result = unsafe {
            MsiEnumRelatedProductsA(
                windows::core::PCSTR(upgrade_code.as_ptr()),
                0,
                index,
                windows::core::PSTR(product_buf.as_mut_ptr()),
            )
        };
        if result == 0 {
            // Convert the null-terminated byte array to a string and print the results
            let product_list = String::from_utf8(product_buf).unwrap_or("".to_string());
            println!("Related products: {}", product_list);
            break;
        } else if result != 259 { //259 = No additional data available
            println!("Error code: {} ({})",result, HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(result));
            break;
        }
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two unrelated issues here:

1. Strings in Rust aren't zero-terminated, but the API expects a zero-terminated string. When called, the API will read beyond the end of the string, until it encounters a value of zero. The behavior is undefined.
2. The upgrade code needs to be enclosed in curly braces. The documentation for [`MsiEnumRelatedProductsA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msienumrelatedproductsa) provides the hint in its description of the output buffer. It requires room for 38 characters, which is two characters more than the GUID string literal currently has.

To fix that you will have to introduce the curly braces, as well as an explicit zero terminator (`\0`). The solution using the least amount of changes is as simple as replacing

```rust
let upgrade_code = "23170F69-40C1-2702-0000-000004000000";
```

with

```rust
let upgrade_code = "{23170F69-40C1-2702-0000-000004000000}\0";
```

You could also just use the [`s!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/macro.s.html) macro provided by the `windows` crate that constructs a `PCSTR` at compile-time, zero-terminated, too, so no one gets hurt:

```rust
MsiEnumRelatedProductsA(
    s!("{23170F69-40C1-2702-0000-000004000000}"),
    0,
    index,
    windows::core::PSTR(product_buf.as_mut_ptr()),
)
```

Though I would recommend a few more changes, specifically the use of the Unicode (UTF-16) API as well as proper error reporting. A complete implementation could look something like this:

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsStr, mem::MaybeUninit};

use windows::{
    core::{Result, HSTRING, PWSTR},
    Win32::{
        Foundation::{ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, ERROR_SUCCESS, WIN32_ERROR},
        System::ApplicationInstallationAndServicing::MsiEnumRelatedProductsW,
    },
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let products = related_products("{23170F69-40C1-2702-0000-000004000000}")?;
    println!("{products:?}");

    Ok(())
}

fn related_products(upgrade_code: impl AsRef<OsStr>) -> Result<Vec<String>> {
    let mut products = Vec::new();

    for index in 0.. {
        const GUID_LEN: usize = 38;
        let mut out_buf = MaybeUninit::<[u16; GUID_LEN + 1]>::uninit();
        let result = unsafe {
            MsiEnumRelatedProductsW(
                &HSTRING::from(upgrade_code.as_ref()),
                0,
                index,
                PWSTR(out_buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _),
            )
        };
        if result == ERROR_SUCCESS.0 {
            let out_buf = unsafe { out_buf.assume_init() };
            let product = String::from_utf16(&out_buf[..GUID_LEN])?;
            products.push(product);
        } else if result == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.0 {
            break;
        } else {
            return Err(WIN32_ERROR(result).into());
        }
    }

    Ok(products)
}
```

*Cargo.toml* dependencies:

```ini
[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.48.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_ApplicationInstallationAndServicing",
]
```